# Python - .csv Calculations by row using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am looking to perform high level calculations on a .csv file. My file has already been grouped from 15 min data series into daily averages. The calculations I am looking to perform involve the data present in each row.

For example my .csv file currently looks something like this:

```
11/03/2014 (value) (value) (value) (value)
```

and I would like to perform a series of calculations based on those daily values in each row.

Is there a way to perform my desired calculations specifically for each row without transposing my columns and rows?

Answer (score 0):

use `apply` with `axis=1`

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': np.random.choice(list('acflmnpsy'), 5),
        'B': np.random.choice(list('ep'), 5),
        'C': np.random.choice(np.arange(60, 241), 5)
    }, pd.date_range('2016-03-31', periods=5)
)
df
```

[image]

And the function I'd like to apply to each row `my_func`

```
def my_func(row):
    return (row.A + row.B) * int(row.C ** .5)

df.apply(my_func, axis=1)

2016-03-31    lplplplplplplplplplplplplplp
2016-04-01    aeaeaeaeaeaeaeaeaeaeaeaeaeae
2016-04-02      yeyeyeyeyeyeyeyeyeyeyeyeye
2016-04-03              ypypypypypypypypyp
2016-04-04        sesesesesesesesesesesese
Freq: D, dtype: object
```